# Vuetify how to make button that displays a v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I wanted to make a custom button that basically when clicked on would make a v-data-table pop out below it. I am basically making a data table show up when a button is clicked and using this transition

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/transitions/#scale

But the transition sort of makes the table go to the right more and also has an active state with a background with opacity, basically there is a lot of built in styles that are making it hard to make a table drop down below the button as the default behavior is when you click on the transition, the item that pops up covers the button.

Below is the code that causes this

```
<v-menu transition="scroll-y-transition" class="scroll-button">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-btn v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
              Scrolling Y Transition
            </v-btn>
          </template>
            <v-data-table> </v-data-table>
        </v-menu>
```

Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code to repro the issue, or provide a demo snippet

Comment: just updated @Zim

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using menu. Maybe you are looking for this kind of animation.

```
<v-btn @click="show = !show">
  {{ show ? 'Hide' ? 'Show' }}
</v-btn>

<v-expand-transition>
  <div v-show="show">
      <v-table></v-table>
  </div>
</v-expand-transition>
```

And in the script

```
data() {
  return {
    show: false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the native props for `v-menu` to reposition the menu how you like. See this snippet: https://codepen.io/bgtor/pen/BaWdBMO .

Note the use of `offset-y` which allow you to offset the menu on the Y axis, and `bottom` which tell it to offset to the bottom. Also, `nudge-left="200px"` is translating the menu to the left by "200px". You can find more props for customisation on the vuetify site: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/.

Other than that, I agree with @scar-2018, it seems odd to display a table in a menu.